# running wireshark from chroot jail

Tags: linux, wireshark, chroot

hi I want to run wireshark from inside a chroot jail.

but when i run it it gives following error:
WARNING: no socket to connect to

I have tried and search everywhere but no explanation so far.
Even if it does not work I want to understand why it is not working.

Comment: `wireshark` is telling you why it's not working:  *no socket to connect to*.  Run it under `strace` to see what exactly it's trying to access.

Comment: if it's a jail, you probably can't put an interface into promiscuous mode.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark uses GnuTLS to try to decrypt SSL/TLS connections.

Apparently [GnuTLS uses gnome-keyring on some systems](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=742776), and gnome-keyring is probably what's printing the messages.

My guess is that it's trying to connect to some daemon running on your machine over a UNIX-domain socket, but the chroot jail is preventing it from accessing the socket.

If that's not preventing Wireshark from running, just ignore the warning.

If it *is* preventing Wireshark from running ("I get a warning when I run X" is not the same as "X doesn't run"), you might not be able to run Wireshark in a chroot jail, unless there's some way to let gnome-keyring connect to that daemon from inside the jail.